# finding top two rows using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Price_trend table in that m_id and c_id are foreign keys. I need m_id column 3,7 top two records.
[Her is my db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cKYuyBaVdbyPmREqjvERer/0)

table: price_trend

| id | c_id | m_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2022-12-08 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2022-12-06 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2022-12-05 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 | 2022-12-03 |
| 5 | 1 | 7 | 2022-12-02 |
| 6 | 1 | 7 | 2022-12-01 |

My Attempt:

I have written the query up to this point, but am stuck on what to do next

```
select * from price_trend where c_id=1 and m_id in(3,7) limit 4;
```

I want result:

| id | c_id | m_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2022-12-08 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2022-12-06 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 | 2022-12-03 |
| 5 | 1 | 7 | 2022-12-02 |

Comment: You can subquery and union - this would be 2 queries in one, each with a limit 2. I have updated your [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cKYuyBaVdbyPmREqjvERer/1)

Comment: But m_id will be dynamic. It will be 3 ,7 or 3,7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On MySQL 8+ we can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m_id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM price_trend
    WHERE c_id = 1 AND m_id IN (3, 7)
)

SELECT id, c_id, m_id, date
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY m_id, date DESC;
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` assigns a sequence 1, 2, 3 to each record in a given `m_id` group, with the most recent record being assigned 1, the next most recent 2, and so on.  In the outer query we then restrict to only records having the first two row numbers.

Comment: That's really cool, didn't know about these features tbh, can you add some explanations of the functions for myself and future readers?

Comment: This query work only in MYSQL8+. My Result Query: select *
from 
 (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by m_id) as r
    from price_trend p where c_id=1 and m_id in(3,7)
     ) rank
     where r <=2;

Comment: [For more information] (http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.X, you can use variables to generate the ranking index. Once you get it, you can select ranking values less or equal to 2.

```
SET @rownum = 0;
SET @prevmid = NULL;

SELECT id, c_id, m_id, date_
FROM (SELECT id, c_id, date_,
             IF(m_id = @prevmid, @rownum := @rownum + 1, @rownum := 1) AS rn,
             IF(m_id = @prevmid, m_id, @prevmid := m_id) AS m_id
      FROM price_trend
      WHERE c_id = 1 AND m_id IN (3, 7)
      ORDER BY id) cte
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hXphkwY85KUQYtHYg3pPy4/0).